# Error accessing local network through PHP

Tags: php

So, basically i'm trying to access the following folder:

```
\\192.168.xx.xxx\C\ATM\ATM_SDOCe\Averbar\11395496
```

But i'm receiving

```
Access denied. (code: 5)
```

i've tried to change the login account on the Wampapache64 service, if i try the same user the wamp is running, it will show me the error **1069 The service did not start due to logon problems**
, so i made a new user and it logged in sucessfully, but, now the php returns this error:

```
Error code 1326. Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running the service with a limited Windows account? This might be the cause.

Comment: I'm checking it right now, but it doesn't seems like it